# JavaScript break sentence at a given word

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string, split

I'm having a situation where my data is coming from server side and I have to break the sentence into two lines,

```
Example: Payment: xyz is done Removal: Refund made
```

Now I have to make this sentence into two lines by adding a `<br>` tag before `Removal`

Need help, tried with `indexOf`, `split` but I am unable to get the workaround.

Comment: Is this string value fixed? or can it be anything else?

Comment: Payment and Removal are fixed after the : data is dynamic

Comment: In that case how would you know where to break the string? Like in this case you know that the string needs to be divided before 'Removal' word

Comment: @SawanPatodia Removal is fixed in the sentence, have to find that and add a br tag before that, thats the challenge im facing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume the `Removal:` part is always present in your `string`.

So what you can do is to :

- Search for the index of the word `Removal` with **[`String#indexOf()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)**.
- then take the two parts according to this `index` using **[`String#substr()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr)**.
- And finally join these two sentences with `<br />` using **[`Array#join()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)**.

This is how should be your code:

```js
var str = "Payment: xyz is done Removal: Refund made";
let ind = str.indexOf("Removal");

let sentences = [str.substr(0, ind), str.substr(ind)];
console.log(sentences.join('<br/>'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write a function to dynamically add this text to the div you want the text to be added to.

I have assumed that you are using JavaScript and HTML only.

Please find below code.

```js
function breakString(str){
  let breakIndex = str.indexOf("Removal");
  let arr = [str.substring(0,breakIndex), str.substring(breakIndex)];
  let parent = document.getElementById("myDiv");
  parent.innerHTML = arr[0] + "</br>" + arr[1];
}        
breakString("Payment: xyz is done Removal: Refund made");
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just split it after `done`:

```
var str = "Payment: abc is done Removal: Refund made";
strArr.split("done");
```

Then add `done` back in, concatenate it, and add the `<br>`:

```
str = strArr[0] + "done <br>" + strArr[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use RegEx to capture every that come before `Removal` and Everything other text that come after include Removal it self.

Because the structure of your text will not change. you will have exactly 3 parts in the `matches` variable

1. The string itself `Payment: xyz is done Removal: Refund made`
2. The text before Removal `Payment: xyz is done`
3. And the remaining text `Removal: Refund made`

```js
chain  = "Payment: xyz is done Removal: Refund made"
matches = chain.match(/(.+)(Removal:.+)/);
console.log(matches.slice(1).join('<br>'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/String/replace) method to do the task, and as it returns a string with the desired replacement(s), your first still there and untouched, so you'd probably use in another task for example.

Here's a demo:

```js
var str = 'Example: Payment: xyz is done Removal: Refund made',
    newStr = str.replace(/(Removal:)/i, '<br />$1');

document.body.innerHTML = newStr;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a regex one:

```
var s = "Payment: xyz is done Removal: Refund made";
var spl = s.split(/^(Payment: [\w]*)\s*(Removal: [\w]*)$/);
console.log(spl[1]+'<br>'+spl[2]);
```

EDIT:

with replace is even nicer

```
var s = "Payment: xyz is done Removal: Refund made";
var spl = s.replace(/^(Payment: [\w]*)\s*(Removal: [\w]*)$/,"$1<br>$2");
console.log(spl);
```